# ¿Como editar registros en laravel7 y mysql?

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un formulario donde llamo a los datos de un producto, para luego editarlo, el problema es que al momento de implementar el update me sale error, y no se porque, este es mi codigo:
Mi archivo web:

```
 Route::get('/productos/{producto}', 'ProductoController@show')->name('productos.show');
 Route::put('/productos/{producto}',  'ProductoController@update')->name('productos.update');
```

Mi vista:

```
<form id="basic-form" method="post"
                                    action="{{ route('productos.update', $producto) }}">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('put')

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                                            <label>Nombre del producto</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="nombreProd" class="form-control"
                                                value="{{ $producto->nombre_producto }}" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                                            <label>Categoria</label>
                                            <select name="categoria" class="form-control"
                                                value="{{ $producto->id_categoria }}" required="required">
                                                <option value="17">Productos Importados</option>
                                                <option value="14">Marcas Propias</option>
                                                <option value="15">Productos Representados</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
```

Y mi controlador:

```
public function show($producto)
    {
        $producto = producto::where('id_producto', $producto)->first();
        return view('admin.pages.producto.show', compact('producto'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, producto $producto)
    {
        $producto->nombre_producto = $request->nombreProd;
        $producto->id_categoria = $request->categoria;

        $producto->save();
        return redirect()->route('productos.index', $producto);
    }
```

Este es el error que me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás seguro que tu modelo es "producto" y no "Producto"? En tu método update

Comment: En tu atributo action, estas pasando $producto como parametro, no deberias pasar el id del producto ?. asi :  action="{{ route('productos.update', $producto->id_producto) }}"

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando en tu controlador el nombre del modelo **Producto** lo siguiente:

```
public function update(Request $request, producto $producto)
public function update(Request $request, Producto $producto)
```

y valida que importaste el modelo Producto.

M